# File Creating On Memory Instead of Hard Disk in VBA Excel Office

Tags: excel, file, vba

When project sends a request to server that request buffer first saves in a text file and that file file saves in a temp folder but on client machine clients antivirus software don't allow to create that file so now for that issue our solution is to create file on memory instead of hard disk. So my question is how to write file on memory/RAM instead of hard disk in VBA Excel Office?

Comment: If the antivirus doesn't allow it, there might be 2 reasons for this. (1) It is a virus/malware or something, which means everything is working fine! (2) It is a false positive, then I would try to exempt this file from being scanned by the antivirus, because this is the easiest way. Are you sure that the antivirus algorithm doesn't detect it if it is saved in RAM? If the antivirus is not completely useless it will trigger a virus here too, so saving it into RAM will not fix your issue anyway I think.

Comment: but i want to store that file temperory on ram after some time it will be clean up so i think that instead of using physical memory we should use RAM

Comment: I think you should re-think your approach. (1) Again, using a RAM disk will also trigger antivirus in the same way as a physical disk (so no benefit). (2) Creating a RAM disk would be cumbersome with VBA because there is no API to create a RAM disk per se. You need to write your own device driver (not possible in VBA) which presents a new disk to the system, and make that device driver work with allocated memory. Or you will need to use 3rd party utilities. Therefore I can only admit re-think your approach. This is definitely a use case for the default system temp directory.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion